# Add Session User Id Into Line_Items table when line item record is created - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord

I am trying to add User Session ID into Line_Items table. I have researched everywhere and couldn't find the answer and that is why had to post it here. This application successfully adds the Phone ID and the Cart ID into the Line_Items table but doesn't let me add user session ID when I try the similar method of Phone and Cart ID. See below for my current implementation:

**Line_Items Controller:**

```
def create
  # current_cart method in application_controller.rb
  @cart = current_cart
  phone = Phone.find(params[:phone_id])
  if phone.stock > 0
    @line_item = @cart.add_phone(phone.id )
    if @line_item.save
      redirect_to  :back, notice: " '#{phone.model}'  has been added to your cart."
    else
      render action: "new" 
    end
  else
    redirect_to  :back, notice: " Cannot add: '#{phone.model}' - stock level is too low."
  end
end
```

**Cart.rb Model**:

```
def add_phone(phone_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by_phone_id(phone_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
  else
    current_item = line_items.build(phone_id: phone_id)
    current_item.quantity = 1
  end
  current_item.phone.stock -= 1
  current_item.phone.save
  current_item
end

# returns true if stock level is greater than zero
def can_add(phone)
  phone.stock > 0
end
```

Please let me know if any further code needed.

Comment: do you get any errors? is there a user_session_id col in the table? how exactly does the code look that fails?

Comment: In the line_items table I have user_id as foreign key to store user_id session which ever user clicks add button, the user session must get inserted into that column. I tried @line_item = @user.add_user(user.id) under if phone.stock > 0 but received undefined local variable or method `user' for #<LineItemsController:0x38c6130>, I guess I don't have an idea how to get the user ID into line_items user_id column

Comment: What is the relationship between phones and users? Is it user has_many phones?

Comment: I do not have any relationship between phones and users but have the relation between user and line_item which is user has_many :line_items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the model classes in Rails don't know anything about the controller nor the session.  I'm presuming you are using some authentication mechanism that gives you a current_user in your session... so we have to get that into your add_phone method.

In the controller, I'd change this line:

`@line_item = @cart.add_phone(phone.id)`

to this:

`@line_item = @cart.add_phone(phone, current_user)`

(notice there are two changes there - one to pass the phone rather than its id, since you already found it, and one to pass the current user.

Then we want to change your add_phone method to look like this:

```
def add_phone(phone, current_user = nil)
  # make sure your Item class initializes quantity to o, not nil.
  current_item = line_items.find_or_initialize_by_phone_id(phone.id)

  current_item.increment!(:quantity)
  current_item.phone.decrement!(:stock)
  current_item.user = current_user
  current_item.phone.save
  current_item
end
```

notice I'm setting the user to nil by default... that way, code you already have that doesn't provide that field will continue to work. I'm also simplifying your method a little bit with the find_or_initialize_by helper... avoids an 'if' test. Also, the increment and decrement helpers clean up the intent of the code a little.

You should make sure your line item class includes

`belongs_to :user`

If you find yourself in a situation where you need to know current_user for a lot of domain logic, you might want to check out the sentient_user gem.

Comment: Thanks a million, this works perfectly when I added the current_user method which I didn't had. But I have another problem. The user_id 2 adds the line_item for product 1 and when the user_id 4 adds the same product, the user_id in table changes to 4 and quantity gets added one. How can I fix that? How about if I use a method to destroy the cart and line_item when user logs out?

Answer (score 1):

**Save**

There could be a number of reasons why your user ID is not being inserted:

> ```
>  - Is `user_id` variable accessible from your model?
>  - How are you saving `user_id`?
>  - Where are you defining the `user_id` variable?
> ```

If you're using an instance method (like in `Cart.rb`) and something like Devise, you likely won't be able to access the `current_user` helper directly; you'll have to pass it through the method:

```
def add_user(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    #etc
end
```

If you post errors or other code pertaining to the user object directly, we'll be in a much better position to help!

---

**Refactoring**

I think you'll benefit from the [increment!](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!) & [decrement!](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/decrement!) methods:

```
def add_phone(phone_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by_phone_id(phone_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.incremenet!(:quality)
  else
    current_item = line_items.build(phone_id: phone_id)
    current_item.quantity = 1
  end
  current_item.phone.decrement!(:stock)
  current_item.phone.save
  current_item
end
```

Comment: I am confused now. I am actually a university student working in this project with my group. Do you think that it is better idea to insert user ID into the Carts table instead of line items table?